# Why is this JavaScript function not called?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function which supposedly reads and parses url variables:

```
function parseError(){
    //get url vars and convert them into javascript vars
    function get(){var vars={};var parts=window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value){vars[key]=value;});return vars;}
    var err_type=get()["t"];
    var err_code=get()["c"];
    var redirect=get()["redirect"];

    //set message based on var data
    var extension = "Hello!";
    if(err_type=1)extension="<a href="+redirect+"><button class=\"dismiss\">Dismiss</button></a>";
    if(err_code=0)err_msg="This site has detected that you currently have javascript turned off. To view this site, you must enable javascript.";
    if(err_code=0)err_msg="When you have javascript enabled, <a href="+redirect+">click here.</a>";

    //write messages to elements
    document.getElementById("err_msg").innerHTML=err_msg;
    document.getElementById("err_sub").innerHTML=err_msg;
    document.getElementById("err_ex").innerHTML=extension;
}
```

And I also have these elements:

```
<body onLoad="parseError();">
<div id="err" align="center">

<div id="err_msg">Loading...</div>
<div class="error_sub">:)</div>
<div class="error_ex"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

It seems like the function isn't even being called.

Sorry that it's a lot of code, but I wasn't sure if a tiny error in the function affected the whole job. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine that the function isn't called? [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: "error_sub" and "error_ex" are class attributes in your html, but you're trying to retrieve them by id.

Comment: Ah. Wow… it's been a long day. :)

Comment: No need to mark something as solved.  However, if one of the answers given worked for you, you should click the check mark to select that answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Initialize your variable `err_msg` within the function :

```
function parseError(){
    //get url vars and convert them into javascript vars
    function get(){var vars={};var parts=window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value){vars[key]=value;});return vars;}
    var err_type=get()["t"];
    var err_code=get()["c"];
    var redirect=get()["redirect"];
    var err_msg="";
    //set message based on var data

    var extension = "Hello!";
    if(err_type=1)extension="<a href="+redirect+"><button class=\"dismiss\">Dismiss</button></a>";
    if(err_code=0)err_msg="This site has detected that you currently have javascript turned off. To view this site, you must enable javascript.";
    if(err_code=0)err_msg="When you have javascript enabled, <a href="+redirect+">click here.</a>";

    //write messages to elements
    document.getElementById("err_msg").innerHTML=err_msg;
    document.getElementById("err_sub").innerHTML=err_msg;
    document.getElementById("err_ex").innerHTML=extension;
}
```

Adjust also your selectors , it is ID and not Class:

```
<div id="err" align="center">

<div id="err_msg">Loading...</div>
<div  id="err_sub">:)</div>
<div id="err_ex"></div>

</div>
```

**DEMO :** 
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/447zF/

Comment: Omitting `var` just makes the variable a global variable rather than a local one, that shouldn't affect it's value once set (although I agree the OP should be more explicit with this).